# KeyWord Extraction from a langchain Agent

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

i am biggner with llm,s and langchain,
What i am trying to do is to have a custom agent or a chain to detect if a keyword exist, for example :
Look this up: who is is Tallest Person?

So **Look this up** detected now i need to call a different Chain like a questions and answer chain
I Cant use tools and the Thought and Action staff and let the llm decide because the open source llm i am using is not that good!

i currently have a memory chat chain that is working with history , is there a way to add a layer before that to decide which chain to use ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the router. This tool `dynamically selects the next chain to use for a given input`.

[Router Docs](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains/foundational/router)